# Django - Extending models with multi role users and multiple requirement types

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django only 2 weeks and I am stuck with scenario I need help with. 
This is kind of core concept and I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge.
I've extended the base user model like below with multiple roles. Now each role has distinct requirements for their profiles.
I need help to understand that how to extend `Students` or `Staff` further. There are two scenario I need to extend them.

1. Both can have similar extended models like addresses below.
2. Both can have different extended models like `Students` have `CurrentCourse` and `Staff` does not. `Staff` has `Salary` model and `Students` does not.

   ```
   class User(AbstractUser):
      is_student = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)


   class Student(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
      dob = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
      location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


   class CurrentCourse(models.Model):
      student = models.OneToOneField(Student,
                                  on_delete=model.CASCADE)
       ....


   class Staff(models.Model):
       ROLES = (('Teacher', 'Teacher'), ('Professor', 'Professor'), ('Administration', 'Administration'))
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
       role = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ROLES)
       website = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   ```

Both types of Users can have multiple addresses and both Students and Staff needs addressess, not sure how to extend this with ForeignKey.

```
   class Address(models.Model):
       user = ?
   street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

  class Salary(models.Model):
   staff = models.OneToOneField(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   current_salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

Finally please let me know how can I apply validators on each model for instance I did sub-classed 'User' to all models instead of Student or Staff. How to apply a validator on OneToOneField like below? I thought that if I apply a validator like:

```
staff_validator(value):
```

I can't call user in validator function and not sure if it will be global or within model its applied on with indent.

```
class Salary(models.Model):
        staff = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, validators=[staff_validator])
```

Thank you in advance for your kind help for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the real world scenario where your `Users` are `People` and `People` can have different roles with the time. Like if I am a `Student` today I belong to "`People`" category and if I will be `Professor` tomorrow still I will belong to `People` category.

So `People` can wear different hats or adapt different roles but they still will be `People`. Similarly your `User` model will always be part of all the roles you need to define in database. So you need to extend your `User` model for not only all the roles in fact for models you believe `User` can be part of and it should be like below:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     .....

class Student(models.Model):
     user =  models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')
     .....

class Courses(models.Model):
     user = models.ManyToMany(User)
```

You need to consult official docs with three types of models. `Abstract` models, `Proxy` models and `Inherited` models for more clarity. Also for creating view for your application you can create checks for your users with `decorators`. [Here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) is a good example as per your question.